# LNK2019 error when linking CPP file for tests

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I am trying to write a Cubic class that performs operations on polynomials of degree 3. When attempting to overload the + operator to return a new Cubic object, it gives me a LNK2019 error:

"unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Cubic::Cubic(void)" (??0Cubic@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: class Cubic const __thiscall Cubic::operator+(class Cubic)" (??HCubic@@QAE?BV0@V0@@Z)"

I've tried looking at whether my function declarations are different from my definitions but they are all the same. I believe the problem is in the overloaded operator because I tried modifying each coefficient using `rhs.coefficient[i] += coefficient[i]` and returning rhs and that worked fine. The reason why I want to return a new Cubic is because it seems more correct and also because it would make it easier to implement the - operator as well.

Cubic.h file

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    class Cubic
    {
    public:
        // Default constructor
        Cubic();
        // Predetermined constructor
        Cubic(int degree3, int degree2, int degree1, int degree0);

        // Return coefficient
        int getCoefficient(int degree) const;

        // Addition op
        const Cubic operator+(Cubic rhs);

        // Output operators
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& outStream, const Cubic& cubic);
    private:
        int coefficient[4];
    };
```

Cubic.cpp

```cpp
#include "Cubic.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Cubic::Cubic(int degree3, int degree2, int degree1, int degree0)
{
    coefficient[3] = degree3;
    coefficient[2] = degree2;
    coefficient[1] = degree1;
    coefficient[0] = degree0;
}

int Cubic::getCoefficient(int degree) const
{
    return coefficient[degree];
}

const Cubic Cubic::operator+(Cubic rhs)
{
    Cubic result;

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result.coefficient[i] = coefficient[i] + rhs.coefficient[i];
    }

    return result;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& outStream, const Cubic& cubic) {
    outStream << showpos << cubic.getCoefficient(3) << "x^(3)"
        << cubic.getCoefficient(2) << "x^(2)"
        << cubic.getCoefficient(1) << "x"
        << cubic.getCoefficient(0);

    return outStream;
}
```

Test.cpp

```cpp
#include "Cubic.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cubic lhs(3, 1, -4, -1);
    Cubic rhs(-1, 7, -2, 3);

    /* TESTS */
    cout << "Addition using + operator" << endl;
    cout << lhs + rhs << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result should be `+2x^(3)+8x^(2)-6x+2`.

Comment: You declared but did not implement the default constructor `Cubic::Cubic()`. As you did use it in `Cubic::operator+()`, the linker looked for the implementation and complained because there is none.

Comment: Changing the declaration to `Cubic() = default;` might fix it. (With this, you refer to the auto-generated of the compiler which is suppressed as soon as a custom constructor is defined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have ***declared*** a default constructor for your `Cubic` class, here:

```cpp
// Default constructor
Cubic();
```

but you have never ***defined*** that constructor (at least, not in any of the code you've shown).

You need to either **define** the default constructor *inline*, like this:

```cpp
// Default constructor
Cubic() { } // This provides a definition, but it doesn't DO anything.
```

or provide a separate definition elsewhere:

```cpp
Cubic::Cubic()
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

You could also add the "Do something" code to the *inline* definition! Most coders would do this if the definition is small (one or two lines) but keep the definition separate for more complex code.

EDIT: Alternatively, as @Scheff has pointed out in the comments, you could explicitly define the default constructor as such using:

```cpp
// Default constructor
Cubic() = default; // Will do minimal required construction code.
```

Comment: @Scheff - Thanks for the typo correction! I was adding my 'edit' when you did it. Hope you don't mind my incorporation of your comment.